# Typescript Overriding Type of String Literals

Tags: typescript, inheritance, enums, literals, subclassing

I currently have the following setup:

```
enum EnumA {
    A,
    AYE
}

enum EnumB {
    B,
    BEE
}

type A = keyof typeof EnumA
type B = keyof typeof EnumB

type AB = A | B

interface IBase {
    foo: (...ok: AB[]) => IBase
}

abstract class Base implements IBase {
    public foo(...ok: AB[]): Base {
        return this
    }
}

class BaseA extends Base implements IBase {
    public override foo(...ok: A[]): Base {
        return super.foo(...ok)
    }
}

class BaseB extends Base implements IBase {
    public override foo(...ok: B[]): Base{
        return super.foo(...ok)
    }
}

const myA: BaseA = new BaseA()
```

I expect that overriding the type of "ok" in the subclasses of Base and implementation of IBase should work, however typescript complains:

> Property 'foo' in type 'BaseA' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'IBase'.
> Type '(...ok: ("A" | "AYE")[]) => Base' is not assignable to type '(...ok: AB[]) => IBase'.
> Types of parameters 'ok' and 'ok' are incompatible.
> Type 'AB' is not assignable to type '"A" | "AYE"'.
> Type '"B"' is not assignable to type '"A" | "AYE"'.ts(2416)

Any ideas what is going wrong here? I'd like to call `myA.foo()` with type declarations that represent the type A, being a subset of type AB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring an interface that expects `A|B` as an argument to a method. Any class that implements that interface must `respect the contract`. This means that passing either `A` or `B` must be acceptable. When you are narrowing the type you are actually violating the contract for either `A` or `B` and this is not ok. What you probably want are generics.

```
enum EnumA {
    A,
    AYE
}

enum EnumB {
    B,
    BEE
}

type A = keyof typeof EnumA
type B = keyof typeof EnumB

type AB = A | B

interface IBase <T> {
    foo: (ok: T) => IBase<T>
}

abstract class Base <T> implements IBase<T> {
    public foo(...ok: T[]): Base<T> {
        return this
    }
}

class BaseA extends Base<A> implements IBase<A> {
    public override foo(...ok: A[]): Base<A> {
        return super.foo(...ok)
    }
}

class BaseB extends Base<B> implements IBase<B> {
    public override foo(...ok: B[]): Base<B>{
        return super.foo(...ok)
    }
}

const myA: BaseA = new BaseA()
```

Here's a playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=31&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAouEEEoG8BQUNQQGnZhAmjKgL6qqiSzwBCKeGNumUNMxZqALgJ4AOwLFAC8UANbAeAewBmUXgNnVICbv0F1RE6XIXAlcSDXJ6smoQB9W5AJYguwAE4yAhgGNBASRouAzoIAeABUAPnoWGSkpAC4oAAopMViggEoRMO8-YGCQ0nIXACNfLkd3Lig3ABs-X1YsqByoGwg+SuAIUC5azP9GtBY+MALKmzcoSKk4gDoZxOSAbQBdFNifXtDwlkxHYC4wRxB5AAsbXwYoMk4qmrr-JGAADwcQABNateyEMObW9s7uj4BL6bDCDYajKBSABuTkcNheggm01mSSwSxWt0+YX6WwwOz2BygvjAAkcUyRMymiRS50u5GuvneWToj2eb0xARo3xabQ69gBWU52POYJGY2hsPhiKiyKpqJo6NWgq5ONx+P2h2JpPJMsp1NpeVQbikIGKUAgPAQSruIigIGAAHdMQg4ikgA)